# C++ passing 4 random characters back to main and forming an array

Tags: c++, function

I am looking to use a function to generate a random character, pass that to the main. The function must be called four times to eventually get an array of 4 chars.

I'm not sure how to call the function multiple times and how to form an array using the chars.

```
char GenChar(char &c))
{
int i;
char c;
for (i=0; i <5; i++)  {
c =  rand( ) % 26 + 65;
return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: The function should just return 1 character, not 4 or 5. Then you can call it 4 times in `main`. The loop should be in `main`, not in the function.

Comment: do you know how to populate any array? Do you really not know how to call a method four times?

Comment: @interjay how would i store the chars in the main when i call it 4 times? I want to put 4 chars into an array P[4] = {c, c, c, c} type of thing, all randomly generated.

Comment: For example, `a[i] = f()` will call `f` and put the result in position `i` in array `a`.

Comment: You declared a extra `char c;` in your function, so the function parameter `char &c` will not be used.
BTW, if you want to generate a char array with only call function one time, you have two solutions, first solution is using a char pointer point to array then pass the pointer to the function, second solution is return a pointer point to an array which generated by `new`.

Comment: Prefer to use character literals, such as `A` instead of their decimal ASCII value.

Comment: BTW, the `return` inside the `for` loop means that function only loops once.

Comment: @interjay that was very helpful! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you want to use *strings* instead of single characters:

```
std::string GenRandomString()
{
  std::string text;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  {
    text += (rand() % 26) + 'A';
  }
  return text;
}
```

In C++ there is a concept difference between single characters and multiple characters.  Multiple characters are called a *string*.

You could also pass by reference:

```
void GenRandomString(std::string& text)
{
  text.clear();
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  {
    text += (rand() % 26) + 'A';
  }
}
```